# Barcode scanning from web browser

Tags: javascript, barcode-scanner

I am working on a web based barcode scanner that needs to scan the PDF417 barcode off a driver's license.  I found a JavaScript that works when scanning sample printed barcodes like below but it does not work on an actual license.  I have created a smartphone app that does work but my goal is to get it working from a browser.

sample image
[image]

Here is the sample code I am working with.  I am pretty sure that the issue has something to do with camera optimization...

'''

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ZXing Barcode Scan</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet';this.onload=null" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300italic,700,700italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet';this.onload=null" href="https://unpkg.com/normalize.css@8.0.0/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet';this.onload=null" href="https://unpkg.com/milligram@1.3.0/dist/milligram.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <main class="wrapper" style="padding-top:2em">

        <section class="container" id="demo-content">
            <h1 class="title">Scan barcode from Video Camera</h1>


            <div>
                <a class="button" id="startButton">Start</a>
                <a class="button" id="resetButton">Reset</a>
            </div>

            <div style="padding: 0px; width: 100%; max-height: 200px; overflow:hidden; border: 1px solid gray">
                <video id="video" style="width: 100%;"></video>
            </div>

            <div id="sourceSelectPanel" style="display:none">
                <label for="sourceSelect">Change video source:</label>
                <select id="sourceSelect" style="max-width:400px">
                </select>
            </div>

            <label>Result:</label>
            <pre><code id="result"></code></pre>

        </section>
    </main>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/@zxing/library@latest"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            let selectedDeviceId;
            const codeReader = new ZXing.BrowserMultiFormatReader()
            console.log('ZXing code reader initialized')
            codeReader.getVideoInputDevices()
                .then((videoInputDevices) => {
                    const sourceSelect = document.getElementById('sourceSelect')
                    selectedDeviceId = videoInputDevices[0].deviceId
                    if (videoInputDevices.length > 1) {
                        videoInputDevices.forEach((element) => {
                            const sourceOption = document.createElement('option')
                            sourceOption.text = element.label
                            sourceOption.value = element.deviceId
                            sourceSelect.appendChild(sourceOption)
                    })

                        sourceSelect.onchange = () => {
                            selectedDeviceId = sourceSelect.value;
        }

                        const sourceSelectPanel = document.getElementById('sourceSelectPanel')
                        sourceSelectPanel.style.display = 'block'
        }

                    document.getElementById('startButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
                        codeReader.decodeOnceFromVideoDevice(selectedDeviceId, 'video').then((result) => {
                            console.log(result)
                            document.getElementById('result').textContent = result.text
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.error(err)
                        document.getElementById('result').textContent = err
        })
        console.log(`Started continous decode from camera with id ${selectedDeviceId}`)
        })

    document.getElementById('resetButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById('result').textContent = '';
        codeReader.reset();
        console.log('Reset.')
        })

        })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err)
                })
        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

'''

Here is a sample of a barcode I cannot scan...
[image]

Comment: What exactly doesn't work, like you mentioned the sample you gave is working. Can you put one that doesn't work?

Comment: Just try the back of a driver's license because that is the actual target.

Comment: My license is Caribbean, we don't have that lol

Comment: I added a sample image that I cannot scan.

Comment: Seems like this is a known issue, the library in question cannot scan this type of barcode, specifically divers licenses.
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/1137

Comment: I have loaded your app on my phose using VSCODE liveserver with localhost SSL and it still seems to not be able to read it even though my camera is perfect so I'm 100% sure its this type of barcode on drivers licenses. Other PDF417 barcodes did work on my phone and computer with your code.

Comment: I have seen many working examples of scanning drivers licenses but they are all paid services. Here is one (https://demo.dynamsoft.com/samples/dbr/js/4.use-case/2.read-a-drivers-license.html).  I am just looking to come up with a solution that doesn't have a large annual fee.  You will see that that solution will scan both samples.

Comment: Check my answer below, does seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, when I zoom in and scan it with a phone with your code it does seem to work. The problem is then that you need the computer to have a nice camera, not even my MacBook 2021's camera is good enough. So they would need like an HD webcam to get up close.

[image]

Comment: It is being designed specifically for a mobile site so scans will be almost always with a smartphone.   I am testing on an IPhone 11 and even zooming in it won't grab that bottom sample.  That's why I was hoping for some camera optimizing tips. What type of phone are you using? And are you using the front camera?

Comment: Im using my google pixel 4 xl, Back camera. never use front camera. It does say front facing but I'm using the back camera.